# Why is GetActiveSheet causing this error?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to add a function to add the values of specific cells depending on their background color. I keep getting the same error though.

N/A

---

```
function sumbycolor(sumRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = activeRange.getFormula().toString();
  formula = formula.replace(new RegExp(';','g'),',');


  var rangeA1Notation = formula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var colorCellA1Notation = formula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(colorCellA1Notation);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();

  var total = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
        total=total+(values[i][j]*1);
   return total;
};
```

---

var activeSheet = activeRange.getActiveSheet();

That line is giving me the error "Cannot call method "GetActiveSheet" of null.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: When you want to retrieve the sheet object from ``var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();``, how about using ``activeRange.getSheet()``? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet

Comment: Same error if I make that change.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, when I modified from ``activeRange.getActiveSheet()`` to ``activeRange.getSheet()``, I can confirm that no error occurs at ``var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();``. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of ``Same error if I make that change.``. So can you provide the detail information for replicating your issue?

Comment: I've created a new function called "sumbycolor". I have copied in the exact code I pasted above and then get the error when trying to test the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I couldn't replicate your situation from your reply comment. But I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Mathew How did you run the function? You should call it as a custom function from inside the sheet. You'll only error, if you run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

[getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveRange()) returns `null` if there is no currently active range. It appears you are trying to add a custom sheets function, not  a function that operates via a UI button or trigger. In fact your function takes two parameters which you never seem to use.

Take a look at [how to process input of a range inside custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)--however, given that [custom functions are passed their arguments as values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#arguments), and not as a range, you will need to pass the range as a string (i.e., `=MYCUSTOMFUNCTION("A1:A")`), and then use `...getRange(input)` within your function.

Comment: This code is foreign to me. I haven't used it much. I'm not sure how to input the change you suggested.

Comment: Google Apps Script is based on Javascript--if you're struggling to understand the basic syntax, a javascript tutorial will get you headed in the right direction. What you are trying to do is act on a [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of the sheet, but when a custom function is provided a range as in normal Sheets formulas, Google Apps Script provides the function with the values within that range (as explained in the link above).

Comment: Because you want to interact with the color of the cells within that range, you will need to instead provide a string as input to your function (as demonstrated above), and use that string to `getRange("A1 notation")` in order to act on it.

Comment: As an example; GAS: `function FONTCOLOR(input) { return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getFontColor(); }`; your custom function: `=FONTCOLOR("A1")`

Comment: Umm... ok... nevermind. I'll just ask someone else.